# Stop a Timer for update checking when PC goes to sleep

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my application I do check for updates on a SQL Server (the zip files get stored in a `varbinary(max)` column, don't ask why it's done this way, it's just the way it is). The application is checking for a new version with a `Timer` every 30 minutes.

Now the problem is if the computer goes to sleep and resumes from it after the next timer cycle I always get an "Could not connect to database ..." error. So I though it should be enough to simply stop the `Timer` when the system goes to standby and resume it when it wakes up.

But it seems like I never even get into the `PowerModeChanged` Event (I've tried to check with writing logs, because I don't think you can debug this Event really).

The code below shows what I'm trying to do, and is from my `App.xaml.cs`:

```
// System.Threading.Timer not System.Timers
private Timer _updateTimer;

private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Do update check on startup
    ...

    var updateTime = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0); // 30 Minutes

    // start update checking in 30 minutes and do it every 30 minutes
    _updateTimer = new Timer(UpdateCheck, null, updateTime, updateTime);

    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += (o, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
                _updateTimer.Dispose();
            else if (args.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
                _updateTimer = new Timer( ... );
        };
}

private void UpdateCheck(object state)
{
    if (Settings.Default.AutoUpdate && UpdateAvailable()) {
        if (MessageBox.Show( ... ) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            DoUpdate();
    }
}

private bool UpdateAvailable() { ... }
private void DoUpdate() { ... }
```

Am I using PowerModeChanged the wrong way? Or is this approach not the best idea at all?

Comment: Is it running from a service or a regular app? (I'm thinking it's a regular app, from the WPF tag, but just want to be sure)

Comment: Why not just test the connection state and connect if it is not connected?

Comment: It's a regular app. Because I can't connect in standby mode, also I want to show a error message if I can not check for updates in normal cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch and catch the exception where it gives error.When computer sleeps it will throw exception and your program will catch that.Program will not stop and will loop again and again. when computer resumes it will start working as normal.

Comment: But with this way I don't get regular exceptions while updating when the PC isn't in standby. I want to show other connection problems to the user. It just sucks that this also comes every time a user wakes up from stand by.